# Cannot Initiatlize Flutter Doctor on intel iMac

Tags: flutter, macos, installation, intel

I'm trying to install Flutter on a 2015 intel powered iMac (see tech specs below).

However, I cannot get "flutter doctor" to initialize in order to check the installation. I've done this successfully on an M1 Macbook Air.

TECH SPECS

Software Overview:

Latest version of Monteray

Hardware Overview:

Model Name:   iMac
Model Identifier: iMac17,1
Processor Name:   Quad-Core Intel Core i5
Processor Speed:  3.2 GHz
Number of Processors: 1
Total Number of Cores:    4
L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
L3 Cache: 6 MB
Memory:   32 GB
System Firmware Version:  522.0.0.0.0
OS Loader Version:    540.120.3~37
SMC Version (system): 2.33f12

I've set the PATH to the bin file in the extracted SDK directory...

export PATH="$PATH:/Users/MyName/Development/flutter/bin"

I've also downloaded homebrew, cocoapods, and XCode in line with Google's documentation. Unfortunately, I'm still not getting any positive effects where flutter doctor would recognize the SDK in the location I described earlier.

I get the following error message: "zsh: command not found: flutter"

I'm at a complete loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, it seems that the terminal is not able to locate the `flutter` command. Maybe you need to just reopen the terminal. If you did that already, maybe check whether the flutter command is actually present at that location.